# Android Select text toolbar options color issue

Tags: android, colors, toolbar, android-appcompat

I'm facing this weird problem with the bar that appears when you select a text

[image]

I'm using Appcompat v7 library the last version. This is my theme defenition:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/material_blue_grey_800</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/TabStyle</item>

    <item name="android:textAppearanceButton">@style/AppTheme.ButtonTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ButtonTextAppearance" parent="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

None of the colors are white, so I don't really know where it comes this white bar color and white icons.

Any clue?

Comment: has your problem been solved?

Comment: It solved automatically on next updates of the appcompat

Comment: Is there anyway to remove the arrow? I cant find the drawable for it

Comment: You should open a new question for that, but you can implement your own custom action bar mode. http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html

Answer (score 4):

In order to make the text selection actionMode background color, use the below in your style:

```
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
<item name="actionModeBackground">@color/dodgerblue</item>
```

Comment: Ahh I've wasted 30 mins looking for this ^_^

Answer (score 0):

try using the following style

```
<style name="customToolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

and in your toolbar add following attributes

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/customToolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Not working... The weird things is that the arrow is black and the menu icons are white...

Comment: Also this doesn't work for text anymore starting with API22 because the Toolbar automatically colors it in contrast color